# GET news feed FROM stream TABLE

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

I am trying to send request for newsfeed to fql through Graph API Explorer on developers page, I am surprised to see that response i got doesn't match fully the news feed on facebook page also the news feed on ios app for facebook. It gets more confusing when i post request through url which responses with totally different list in XML, which shows something extra which doesn't show on my news feed on facebook page.

the query i send with fql from Graph API Explorer

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0
```

and through URL i send

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20post_id%2C%20actor_id%2C%20target_id%2C%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20filter_key%20in%20(SELECT%20filter_key%20FROM%20stream_filter%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme()%20AND%20type%3D'newsfeed')%20AND%20is_hidden%20%3D%200&access_token=<access token>
```

I am searching for answer for a week now an i didn't find nothing useful, tried this from other account and i see same problem.

I tryed also to see what facebook app for ios request and i got a link which looks like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/graphql/
```

with a POST parameters

```
sdk_version=3 
format=json
app_version=40121
q=node(1033280756){home_stories.environment(iphone).first(5){edges{deduplication_key,...<in very long query>
locale=en_US
method=get
sdk=ios
access_token=<access token>
```

but testing it with Graph API Explorer with access token from GAE i recieve message

> {
>     "error": {
>       "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: graphql", 
>       "type": "OAuthException", 
>       "code": 803
>     }
>   }

this only works and response totally match my news feed from facebook page when i gave access token from my ios facebook app and when i try to get access token through `https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=6628568379` i receive the same error.

I cant understand is this a bug in table or this isnt the way how you get news feed like facebook gets?
Did anybody got any official answer from facebook?

Comment: Is `/me/home` not approximating the native news feed closely enough

Comment: no, also /me/home doesn't show the same, it hides some posts (it shows smth but hides some other posts, special shares are missing)

Comment: trying to find pattern what is missing and it looks like it doesnt find shares and likes. example: `https://graph.facebook.com/354713911283059/` responds with message `{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}` and in news feed it says `<friend> shared a page: <the page name>.`